# Cambiar dinámicamente el nombre de una clase con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una duda con ésta función que tengo implementada en un ejercicio y tengo la duda siguiente...

```
for (var i = 0; i < presenter.configuration.texts.count; i++) {
        var text = presenter.configuration.texts.content[i];
        var textElement = document.createElement('div');
        $(textElement).addClass('slideshow-container-text');
        $(textElement).html(text.text);
        $(textElement).css({
            top:text.top + 'px',
            left:text.left + 'px'
        });
        presenter.configuration.texts.domReferences[i] = textElement;
        $(DOMElements.container).append(textElement);
    }
```

Cómo puedo hacer que él dinámicamente, si hay 4 divs de texto, en la clase que se llama 'slideshow-container-text' me añada un caracter o número más para crear en ese bucle clases individuales a esos 4 divs creados?.

Gracias!.

Comment: http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/anadir-quitar-class-jquery.html espero y te ayude esta pagina es muy buena http://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-addclass-removeclass-4705/ este es otro sitio en el ke te puede ayudar

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de crear las clases diferentes? Seguramente haya una mejor forma de llegar a lo que estás intentando sin la necesidad de crear clases diferentes.

Comment: El objetivo es tener clases individualizadas porque uso un gestor de contenidos privado y esa es la única forma que tengo de trabajar. Actualmente todos los div manejan la misma clase pero para casos concretos, necesito individualizar y la única forma que los crea es dinámicamente vía 'for'.

Comment: Bien. Es raro, pero si es un caso particular del que estás seguro... ya publicaron la respuesta a esto.

Comment: Si, aunque aún no he logrado cómo enfocarlo para que me lo acepte éste gestor jeje.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con el código que ya tienes.

Cambia tu `addClass` por:

```
$(textElement).addClass('slideshow-container-text' + i);
```

No sé si necesitas, además, algo de lógica para eliminar esas clases secuenciales.

Comment: Listo! todo genial :)